# PDO, MySQL - How do I return an array from a function?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, pdo, return

I am using a function to retrieve multiple rows from a mysql database. I use a foreach to loop through each match. I want to be able add the id of each row to an array and return the array back to the calling program to then use the id's.

This is as far as I have tried to get, am I going in the correct direction?

```
$resultarray = array();
    $resultarray[] = get_post_data($post_id);

    print_r($resultarray);
```

code in function:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = ?");
        $stmt->bindParam(1,$post_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $resultarray = array();
        foreach($stmt as $row):


                $resultarray[] = $img_id = $row['img_id'];


        endforeach;
        return $resultarray;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

}
```

Instead of the for loop. You are also highly encouraged to use { and } for things like loops :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the `img_id` field, why are you running `select *`?

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT img_id FROM mjbox_images JOIN mjbox_posts USING (post_id) WHERE post_id = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$post_id);
$stmt->execute();

return $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Alternatively you could loop through the results manually (to validate/change the return array syntax) with:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //code
}
```

Comment: actually I need multiple bits of data but wanted to make the example easier just by using img_id. How do I get each set of data into its own key in the array?

Comment: @crm using `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`? You can use `PDO::FETCH_COLUMN` as the fetch type for `PDOStatement::fetchAll()`, which gives you what [i think] you're looking for. Though if you plan on looping through the results manually I'd stay away from fetchAll and use fetch, as above